# Cuál sería mi Capa de Acceso a Datos?

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

quisiera pedirles que me orienten ya que estoy algo perdido, necesito saber cual sería la capa de acceso a datos o DAO en mi proyecto ya que no estoy usando DAO, uso la arquitectura JEE 6 pero me pidieron documentar un proyecto y no se me ocurre cual puede ser mi Capa de Acceso a Datos o la que cumpla esa función, ya que no estoy usando DAO pero se supone que si cumplo con ese punto porque cuando me evaluaron la primera parte me dijeron que si lo cumplí solo que ahora me pidieron documentar todo en orden, buscando en foros he logrado identificar mi Capa de Negocio que resultan ser los Session Beans del paquete "service" que estoy usando de ejemplo con la base de datos del netbeans para demostraciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego tendría los Pojos y la clase AbstractFacade en el mismo paquete service de los Session Bean que operan sobre los pojos, podrían orientarme al respecto ? muchas gracias por su tiempo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu capa de acceso a datos estaría conformada por aquellas clases que se comunican directamente con la base de datos o archivos, dónde tengas estructurados los datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EntityManager en conjunto con las clases T entity (segun  el nombre de parámetro que usaste en tu codigo) que utilices para los accesos a la base de datos estan conformando tu DAO. Complementando la explicación anterior.

Comment: Muchas gracias :), también se me ocurría que podía esa, una vez más gracias (y)